# How to update version to reflect git's index change?

Tags: git, sbt

I've been trying to find a way to ensure the version reflects that of the current git index and haven't found a way to do so yet, e.g.:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(GitPlugin)

root.settings(
  isSnapshot in ThisBuild <<= git.gitUncommittedChanges in ThisBuild,
  version in ThisBuild <<= (git.gitDescribedVersion in ThisBuild, isSnapshot in ThisBuild) { (described, isSnapshot) =>
    described.map(tag => if (isSnapshot) s"$tag-SNAPSHOT" else tag).get
  },
  shellPrompt := { state => {
    val (describe, snapshot) = GitKeys.gitReader.value.withGit(git => (git.describedVersion.get, git.hasUncommittedChanges))
    val newVersion = s"$describe${if (snapshot) "-SNAPSHOT" else ""}"
    if (newVersion != version.value) {
      s"${scala.Console.RED}*** Version out of date ($newVersion vs ${version.value}), reload.\n${scala.Console.RESET}> "
    } else "> "
  }}
)
```

While this will warn the user if the version no longer reflects whats in Git and request a reload, it would be nice if the version would update automatically on this change...

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What version of sbt do you use? You may want to use `enablePlugins(GitPlugin)` amongst other goodies with 0.13.8.

Answer (score 2):

That is not quite what I was asking. After a lot of work, this seems to do the trick (even though it requires the user to enter a command):

```
val checkVersion = taskKey[Unit]("check-version")

def createVersion(git: GitReadonlyInterface) : (String, Boolean) = {
  val (tag, snapshot) = (git.describedVersion.get, git.hasUncommittedChanges)
  (s"$tag${if (snapshot) "-SNAPSHOT" else ""}", snapshot)
}

def updateVersion = Command.command("update-version") { state =>
  val extracted = Project.extract(state)
  val (newVersion, snapshot) = extracted.get(GitKeys.gitReader).withGit(createVersion)
  extracted.append(Seq(version := newVersion, isSnapshot := snapshot), state)
}

commands += updateVersion
version <<= (GitKeys.gitReader) { _.withGit(createVersion)._1 }
isSnapshot <<= (GitKeys.gitReader) { _.withGit(createVersion)._2 }
checkVersion <<= (GitKeys.gitReader, version, isSnapshot).map { (git, version, isSnapshot) =>
   val (newVersion, snapshot) = git.withGit(createVersion)
   if (version != newVersion) {
      sys.error("Version out of date, please run 'update-version'")
   }
}
update <<= update.dependsOn(checkVersion)
compile <<= compile.dependsOn(checkVersion)
```

This solution ensures that the project's version and snapshot are up-to-date *and* provides a *very fast* 'version+snapshot only' reload.

If you have large projects where reload could take a while, this is quite efficient.

What would be a lot better is if "version in ThisBuild" was not memoized across the SBT session, rather it is reevaluated as part of the scope. Now, if someone had "version in Global", this would not be the case.

Specifically, the issue at hand is that "version" needs to be calculated within the Scope of the user's top-level task request.

Comment: Nice answer!  you could probably add such a command (and hook) to SbtGit itself!

Answer (score 1):

`version` is a setting (fixed when sbt loads), so you have to `reload` to refresh the setting's value.

```
> inspect version
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] Description:
[info]  The version/revision of the current module.
...
> help reload
reload

    (Re)loads the project in the current directory.

reload plugins

    (Re)loads the plugins project (under project directory).

reload return

    (Re)loads the root project (and leaves the plugins project).
```